Efficient Molecular Pattern Recognition in Mathematica for Large-Scale Molecule Classification
Currently, I have a series of molecules. As you can see, they have a consistent structure.


I now want to use Mathematica's molecular pattern recognition to automatically find similar structures among them and then classify them. It can be done manually, but it's too cumbersome because I have a large number of molecules. I understand that MoleculePattern can be used for patterns, but I don't know how to write this substructure. The examples in the help documentation seem to be very simple examples that don't work well for practical cases. I've tried using the MoleculeMaximumCommonSubstructure function, but I found it to be too slow. Please help me, thank you.
The code you provided in Mathematica is as follows:
importG16[x_] := Import[x, "GaussianLog"];

path1 = "https://pan.wxyhgk.com/d/local/molcule/GDG39s0.log";
path2 = "https://pan.wxyhgk.com/d/local/molcule/GDG40s0.log";
path3 = "https://pan.wxyhgk.com/d/local/molcule/GDG41s0.log";

data = importG16 /@ {path1, path2, path3}

comS = MoleculeMaximumCommonSubstructure@data

GraphicsRow[MoleculePlot[#, comS , ImageSize -> Small] & /@ data]

Then I got a little idea and made a highlight with SMART
MoleculePlot3D[data[[1]], 
 Style[{MoleculePattern["c1cc[#7]cc[#5]cc[#7]cc1"]}, LightYellow],
 SphericalRegion -> True
 ]



Can you explain further what is the expected output? What is the definition of distance? What distance threshold separates something "similar" from something else? What is  "too slow", how many files do you need to process and how much time would be acceptable?

In addition to rhermans' comment: 1. If I understand your question correctly, the phrase "similar structures" isn't proper for describing what you want, please reconsider it a bit. 2. Have you tried MoleculeDraw, AtomList and BondList?

Like molecule one, molecule two... Molecule n has a similar structure, and B-N-B in the middle is basically the parent nucleus of this molecule

You don't have to write the SMILES code for a molecule created by Molecule as it creates it.   data above comes back with three Molecules.  Simply click on the + of one them to see the SMILES code.  To extract the code from a molecule, one way is to  download SmilesString from the Wolfram function repository.  Then for example if you want the SMILES code for the first molecule in data above, simply code SmilesString[data[[1]]].  Perhaps you can work with the SMILES code directly to identify similar structures.  Google SMILES for more info about coding molecules.

@josh I don't know how to define similarity here, so it bothers me, you know

You would have to learn how.  Start with simple molecules, Learn how to code SMILES.  Study the patterns, maybe something would emerge.

@josh ok,thanks

…So I fail to guess out what you mean, too. (The highlighting in my mind is not the same as shown in your update. ) Please clarify the meaning of "similar structures among them" and "classify them". Also, please clarify the "too slow" part, do you mean the code runs forever, or something else? The question will be reopened once it becomes clear enough. Finally, let me repeat my words here: Perhaps you're having difficulty in reality, but it's not a reason for asking careless question in this site.
